# Чи можна вживати слово "роди" у значенні "пологи"?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, архаїзми

У сучасній українській мові слово *"роди"* вже давно відійшло в давнину і сприймається як русизм, що походить від *"роды"*.

Незважаючи на це, воно все ще зустрічається у літературі, зокрема, юридичній.

Так, у Кодексі законів про працю України (Документ №322-08, поточна редакція від 20.01.2018 р.) у ч.5 ст. 40 серед виключного переліку випадків, які уможливлюють розірвання трудового договору з ініціативи власника, зустрічається наступна фраза: *"не рахуючи відпустки по вагітності **і родах**"*.

Тому виникає питання стосовно правильності вживання даного слова.

Словник української мови: в 11 тт. / АН УРСР. Інститут мовознавства; за ред. І. К. Білодіда. — К.: Наукова думка, 1970—1980. — Т. 8. — С. 90. [містить таке визначення](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/slovnyk_ukrainskoi_movy_v_11_tomakh/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8):

> ***ПОЛО́ГИ*** 1, ів, мн. Фізіологічний процес виходу плода з тіла матері; роди.

Цей же словник наводить і визначення того, що таке "роди":

> ***РО́ДИ***, ів, мн., рідко. Те саме, що поло́ги (1).

Вікіпедія ж не містить поняття *"роди"*, натомість - *"пологи"*.

На різноманітних сайтах про материнство (на кшталт, ["Я-матуся"](http://ya-matusya.com.ua/pologi-i-pislyapologoviy-period-vidverto-i-bez-prikras/))  переважно зустрічається слово *"пологи"*.

*Зважаючи на все вищевикладене, виникає запитання: чи буде правильним та доцільним вживати слово "роди" замість "пологи"?*

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Дякуємо, що приєдналися до спільноти.

Comment: Ви могли би підкріпити думку про "русизм"?

Comment: Тут містяться вказівка на те, що поняття "роди" та "родильний будинок" є помилковими: https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%97:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Словники](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on), що передували 11-томному Тлумачному, не містять слово роди.

Російсько-український словник 1930р. (О. Ізюмов)

> Роды – ро́диво, -ва, поло́ги, -гів.

Словник українсько-російський 1927р. (А. Ніковський)

> Зло́ги, -гів –  1) роды;
>
> Ро́диво –  1) роды;
>
> Роді́ння – рожание, роды.

Словарь української мови 1909р. (Б. Грінченко)

> Зло́ги, -гів, м. мн.  1) Роды. Балт. у.   По́лог, -гу, м.  1) Роды,
>   разрѣшеніе отъ бремени.
>
> Роди́ни, -ди́н, ж. мн.  1) Рожаніе, роды.
>
> Роді́ння, -ня, с. Рожаніе, роды.

На захист слова роди є думка [тут](https://kak-pravilno.net/pologi-chi-rodi-yak-pravilno/).