# Післяпологова чи післяродова депресія?

Tags: вибір-слова

На різних жіночих сайтах-порадниках, наприклад, на [Поради подруги](http://womens-life.org/simeyniy-zatishok/pislyarodova-depresiya/) знаходжу поради як боротися з **післяродовою** депресією. Однак, на одному медичному порталі,зокрема, [Медичний портал UFMM](http://www.ufmm.org.ua/stati/shho-take-pislyarodova-depresiya/) знаходжу в 1 статті 2 терміни **післяродова і післяпологова** депресія. У СУМі знаходжу 2 слова з однаковим значенням: [пологи](http://sum.in.ua/s/pologhy):

> **ПОЛОГИ** 1, ів, мн. Фізіологічний процес виходу плода з тіла матері; **роди.**

і [роди](http://sum.in.ua/s/rody):

> **РОДИ,** ів, мн., рідко. Те саме, що **пологи**.

Отже, чи в офіційних медичних документах буде нормативно вживати ці 2 терміни? Чи **післяродова депресія**  можна вживати лише в розмовному мовленні?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не можу сказати, що я повністю погоджуюсь з аргументацією у [відповіді @MariiaMatskevych](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/4613) — адже іноді слово, цілком вживане у наш час, може базуватися на застарілому корені/основі/тощо. Але згоден із висновком, хоч аргументуватиму його по-іншому — *післяпологовий* частіше зустрічається в словниках і у практичному вжитку, ніж *післяродовий*:

- Академічний «Російсько-український словник» А. Кримського і С. Єфремова (1924–1933) містить [*післяполо́говий* (а також ***по**поло́говий* і *післяро́д**ивн**ий*)](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9&scope=rusb&dicts=1), але не *післяродовий*.
- «Українсько-англійський словник» К. Андрусишина і Я. Крета (1955) містить [*післяполого́вий* (а також *післярод**и́вн**ий*)](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=after+birth&dicts=8), але не *післяродовий*.
- «Словник української мови» в 11 томах (1975) містить [*післяполо́говий*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pisljapologhovyj), але не *післяродовий*.
- У корпусі ГРАК-3 [*післяпологовий* зустрічається 39 разів](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9), а [*післяродовий* — 17](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9).
- У «Google Книгах» [*післяпологовий* зустрічається приблизно 108 разів](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&lr=lang_uk&q=%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&num=100&start=100), а [*післяродовий* — приблизно 74](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&lr=lang_uk&q=%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&num=100).

Отож ***післяполо́говий*** (у деяких словниках чомусь *післяполого́вий*) здається вживанішим і відомішим, ніж *післяродовий*.

<sub>Окрім (можливо, застарілих) варіантів ***по**поло́говий* і *післяро́д**и́вн**ий*, що були випадково знайдені і зазначені вище, є ще варіант *постната́льний* (згадується у [«Словниках України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/), [«Словнику іншомовних слів» Мельничука](http://slovopedia.org.ua/42/53407/288395.html) і [«Великому тлумачному словнику української мови» Бусела](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Дивіться відповідь на питання [Чи можна вживати слово “роди” у значенні “пологи”?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3638/%D0%A7%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%96-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8) цього ж сайту.

Оскільки в визначенні слова "роди" є позначка *рідко*, краще його не вживати в офіційних документах.

Отже, в офіційних медичних документах правильно вживати ***післяпологова депресія***. ***Післяродова депресія*** вживається лише в розмовному мовленні.